# Downloading files into a folder inside android application

Tags: android, download, storage

Sorry if this question was asked many times,
But i want to store some files inside my application,,i tried to put them in Raw folder ,,ok it works i can load them when ever i want,,
But can i modify them at run time??
can i download new files and put them in the Raw folder?

I want to do that because if i put them in the SD card...the user can see them without the application, and i don't want that to happen..

Internal Memory is not an option too,,

i aslo used this path..but the files can be seen

```
  directory = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()  +"/data/"+getPackageName()+"/files"); 

directory.mkdirs();


if(DeleteFlag!=1 || !downloadTask.isCancelled()){

file1 = new File(directory, audioFileName); 

output = new FileOutputStream(file1);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) { 
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> But can i modify them at run time?? can i download new files and put them in the Raw folder?

No. Resources are read-only at runtime. Please store downloaded material either in internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()` or external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`).

> I want to do that because if i put them in the SD card...the user can see them without the application, and i don't want that to happen..

They can see everything without the application. They can see your raw resources without the application. If they root their device, they can see anything they want without the application. If you have data that you do not want the users to have access to, store it on the Internet and leave it there.

Of course, users tend to prefer apps that do not waste bandwidth and do not try to hide data from them.

Comment: thanks for your comments..
So i can't download files to the application space at run time...
i found class called Context Wrapper with Method (openFileOutput)

Does it relate to my issue??